# Is there a way to define Android/iOS build version on Ionic / cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I need to test some scenarios when a user has an old version of my app installed, so I check the app version ([using cordova plugin app version](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version)) and if it is different to the version stored in database then I do some things to get all up to date.

I want to do this with something more detailed like build version. I am not sure how to do this. Do i use [Aditional Versioning](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref/index.html#additional-versioning) ? How can I check that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use *versionCode* like in the doc you link to, then use cordova or even easier ngCordova to fetch the versionCode and compare.. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/appVersion/

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you try to add versions in the config.xml file

```
<widget android-versionCode="273" id="XXXXXXXX" version="0.1.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

in this line you can find in top of the config.xml file no need plugin for that. You can change android-versionCode and ios version in version="0.1.3"

Comment: What I need is to check that version vs older ones